# MySQL Join with several CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

I need some help with MySQL where I want to JOIN with a CASE WHEN. I am getting 3 columns from statement below.

I would like to add from table Customer.name so I get a 4th column with Customer Name. 
Table CustomerCategory has foreign key and ID from Customer.CustomerID
Also every customer has an id but not necessary a CustomerCode, null exists. 
Tried many versions of join but...

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST01" THEN "Distributor" ELSE " " END ) AS Distributor,
(CASE   when when CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST02" THEN "Retail" ELSE " " END ) AS Retail,  
(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST03" THEN "Enduser"   ELSE " " END ) AS Enduser
from CustomerCategory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youd sould use a JOIN

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST01" THEN "Distributor" ELSE " " END  AS Distributor
 , CASE WHEN CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST02" THEN "Retail" ELSE " " END  AS Retail
 , CASE WHEN CustomerCategory.CustomerCode = "CUST03" THEN "Enduser"   ELSE " " END  AS Enduser
 , Customer Name
from CustomerCategory
INNER  JOIN  Customer ON Customer.ID  = CustomerCategory.CustomerID
```

Comment: @Strawberry   .. when when removed ..